# How to navigate to a login page instead of MainPage

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, stack-trace

I'm in a sticky position. I have a published app and have been receiving Crash Reports. Most of which is `InvalidOperationException`. All the 19 frames in the stacktrace shows internal functions and hence Im not able to figure out which function raised it. With a lot of debugging, I think I InvalidOperation Exception is caused by the way I redirect navigation to a Login page.

The basic operation is like this. If the user has set a password, it navigates to the password page else to MainPage. The code as follows

```
App()
{
   // the usual code
   RootFrame.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(RootFrame_Navigating);
}


void RootFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("/RootPage.xaml") != true)
            return;

        CycleManager pCycMan = CycleManager.Instance;

        e.Cancel = true;
        RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
        {
            if (pCycMan.GetPasswordEnabled())
                RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/PasswordPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        });
}
```

The RootPage mentioned above is defined in `<App>` tag in `WMAppManifest.xml`

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="RootPage.xaml" />
</Tasks>
```

When I debugged the above codes, I found the same call stack as the StackTrace. Could someone tell me if this is the correct method of navigating to a page other Mainpage? I have included StackTrace below

```
"Frame    Image             Function                                                Offset    
0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                      19        
1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            436488    
2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            386545    
3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            540936    
4                          TransitionStub                                          0         
5                          System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate    1580      
6                          System.Windows.Controls.Frame.Navigate                  80        
7                          .__c__DisplayClass5._Application_Activated_b__3         136       
8        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            429164    
9        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            185803    
10       mscoree3_7.dll                                                            84423    
11                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke      112       
12                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke      1564      
13                         System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke                     104       
14                         System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne                        564      
15                         System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl              84        
16                         System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke     80        
17                         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch            404       
18                         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke            56        
19                         System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke            84"
```

Thanks for the patience in reading such a long Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the navigation you can achieve it like this.

Get the UriMapper from the app.xaml resources, and assign it to the root frame

```
UriMapper mapper = Resources["mapper"] as UriMapper;
RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;
```

and then Update the mapper as appropriate

```
if (IsPasswordSaved)
                mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/PasswordPage.xaml?method=UriMapper", UriKind.Relative);
            else
                mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?method=UriMapper", UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: Thanks @pan4321. I have used Urimapper as suggested but once it enters the login page it does not further navigate to mainpage on entering password. I have the following check at the Password Page
  
    `if (passwordBox1.Password == pCycMan.GetPassword()
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: Can u clear the ambiguity that Login page and Password page are same or different and how you wants the navigation of pages.

Comment: So if a password is set, it navigates to the password page. And after entering the password, onclick of enter button it does not navigate to the MainPage

Comment: Ok thats fine, 3 queries on this. 1) after entering password where does it navigate if does not navigate to mainpage. 2) if password is not set where does it navigate 3) On what condition you want to navigate it into Mainpage

Comment: 1) After entering password it does not navigate to MainPage. I want it to naviagte to MainPage. 2) When password is not set, it navigated to MainPage which is the expected behaviour.3) After entering password, if the password is correct I want to navigate to MainPage.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Torr has a great article on just this thing here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

HTH
Rupert.

Comment: This method is not workin, It keeps circling inside the `RootFrame_Navigating` function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, I followed the cue given by @pan4321 with minor modification.

This is how I finally did it.

I have set the default navigation in `WMAppManifest` to a nonexistent page called RootPage.xaml

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="RootPage.xaml" />
</Tasks>
```

App.xaml has the following in its `<Application` tag

```
xmlns:UriMapper="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Navigation;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">
```

And in the `<Application.Resources` tag

```
<UriMapper:UriMapper x:Name="mapper">
   <UriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/RootPage.xaml" />
</UriMapper:UriMapper>
```

Inside the `App()` I call the `SetupUriMapper()`

```
void SetupUriMapper()
    {
        // Get the UriMapper from the app.xaml resources, and assign it to the root frame
        UriMapper mapper = Resources["mapper"] as UriMapper;
        RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;

        // 
        CycleManager pCycMan = CycleManager.Instance;
        bool isPasswordSet = pCycMan.GetPasswordEnabled();

        // Update the mapper as appropriate
        if (isPasswordSet)
            mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/PasswordPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        else
            mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
```

Now as to why I changed the default navigation to "RootPage.xaml" than the usual MainPage.xaml  is simply because after navigating to password page, on entering password and clicking ok I'm not able to navigate to MainPage.xaml. It stays inside to the same page PasswordPage.

I found few answers strewn all across the web and this is how I comprehended. On PasswordPage after checking the condition and if it is true it should ideally navigate to MainPage.xaml. But if we have set our default page as MainPage.xaml in WMAppManifest file, it would not navigate because it is looking for a new Uri  [`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`] for navigating and our default current navigation is still set to MainPage.xaml. Since there is no change in Uri, it stays at PasswordPage. But if we define our default page as RootPage, on reaching the PasswordPage, our navigating Uri is MainPage while our default Uri is RootPage.

```
 if (passwordBox1.Password == pCycMan.GetPassword())
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Hope this is of help to somebody. Please correct me if I have got it wrong.